# Cannot add users to ACL from Windows on a SMB share because windows uses wrong username to login to LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, samba, smb

I have a running Samba as Active Directory Domain Controller with shares. I have Windows 10 clients. These clients have Windows Home edition so they cannot join the domain. What I want is to be able to access the share from windows using specified credentials and the ability to edit ACLs from Windows.

So far I can connect to the share and create files inside of it. I can also set the ACL from **linux**. I can also edit ACL from Windows for users that already have some permissions. (Are visible in the permission window on Windows).

What I cannot do is to add permission to an existing user from Windows. The Windows is trying to find the user using wrong credentials (when adding the user to ACL). Windows is using its **hostname** as username to login to the LDAP server (managed by the same Samba instance) instead of using the username that is logged in to the share.

I have confirmed this weird behavior using Wireshark.

My domain name: PRESTOL
User with access to the share: PRESTOL\Administrator
The actual user windows is logging in while trying to find the user: Hostname of the windows machine.

Is there a way to force the windows client to list the users using the user accessing the share (PRESTOL\Administrator) instead of the client hostname?

Thank you.

Comment: Clarification: the windows tries to log using its hostname as domain name and using local username.

Comment: I think I have found a solution: C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /netonly /user:Administrator@prestol.cz "C:\totalcmd\TOTALCMD64.EXE" then I can go to the properties and add a user to ACL, because windows is using correct credentials.